# Node Angular JWT persistent connection

Tags: node.js, angular, express, jwt

I have a problem, All my JWT manage without token works, but when i reload I lose all auth.

So I'm trying to get persistent token. with using the localstorage. but it didn't work.

I'm trying to check if token duration is ok for persistent auth. I'm think my code is correct but dont know where is the bug. I think it's in the auth service . But i don't know why.

**NodeJS login code**

```
exports.login = (req, res, next) => {
    Userbo.findOne({ email: req.body.email }).then(
      (userbo) => {
        if (!userbo) {
          return res.status(401).json({
            error: new Error('User not found!')
          });
        }
        bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, userbo.password).then(
          (valid) => {
            if (!valid) {
              return res.status(401).json({
                error: new Error('Incorrect password!')
              });
            }
            const token = jwt.sign(
              { userId: userbo._id },
              'RANDOM_TOKEN_SECRET',
              { expiresIn: 7200 });
            res.status(200).json({
              userId: userbo._id,
              token: token,
              role : userbo.role,
              expiresIn: 7200,
            });
          }
        ).catch(
          (error) => {
            res.status(500).json({
              error: error
            });
          }
        );
      }
    ).catch(
      (error) => {
        res.status(500).json({
          error: error
        });
      }
    );
  }
```

**Angular auth.service**

```
login(email: string, password: string) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.http.post(
        'http://localhost:3000/api/authbo/login',
        { email: email, password: password })
        .subscribe(
          (authData: { token: string, userId: string, role: string, expiresIn: Number }) => {
            this.token = authData.token;
            this.userId = authData.userId;
            localStorage.setItem('id_token', authData.token);
            const expiresAt = moment().add(authData.expiresIn.valueOf(), 'second');
            localStorage.setItem("expires_at", JSON.stringify(expiresAt.valueOf()));

            this.role = authData.role;
            this.isAuth$.next(true);
            console.log('LOGIN' + this.isAuth$);
            resolve();
          },
          (error) => {
            reject(error);
          }
        );
    });
  }

  logout() {
    this.isAuth$.next(false);
    this.userId = null;
    this.token = null;
    this.role = null;
    localStorage.removeItem("id_token");
    localStorage.removeItem("expires_at");
  }

    public isLoggedIn() {
      return moment().isBefore(this.getExpiration());
    }
    getExpiration() {
      const expiration = localStorage.getItem("expires_at");
      const expiresAt = JSON.parse(expiration);
      return moment(expiresAt);
    }
```

I don't know if the token is created well ? someone can help me ? :)

Comment: Go to https://jwt.io and paste your token here and check the expiration property if you are not certain about your expiration duration. You are expiring your token after 7200ms.

Comment: it says it's good   https://jwt.io/#debugger-io?token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VySWQiOiI1Y2FiMjIzNmU1YThjZjMzMTRiNTQ5MzciLCJpYXQiOjE1NTU3ODAyNDYsImV4cCI6MTU1NTc4NzQ0Nn0.bilEKvQOnPMc9waZbENQ2gFpt19HGqeWOYfy13Xwahc

Comment: It doesn't make any sense to me. Your token should expire in 7200ms according to your code.

Comment: Yes but the problem is when I tried to read token to validate auth. It doesn't work